# How to add multiple attributes to all the vertices in igraph?

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph

I have 49 attributes for 27000 vertices each in an igraph.

```
vertex_features <- list()
for (i in seq(1, length(V(g)))){
  
  vertex_id <- V(g)[i]
  
  a <- df[df$username == vertex_id$name, cols]
  feature_vector <- unlist(a)
  vertex_features[[i]] <- feature_vector
  
}

set_vertex_attr(g,name = 'featurex', value = vertex_features)

print(vertex_attr_names(g))
```

I am using this code to add attributes to each vertex. However when I print the vertex attribute names I only get "name" as the attribute and not the other 49 attributes that I have added. Kindly let me know whats wrong with my code. The for loop runs properly and adds all the features to the vertex_features list in correct sequence.

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible example for your question? it would be much easier for others to help you with specific data.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks I figured it out. I had to write g<- set_vertex_attr(g,name = 'featurex', value = vertex_features).